# One Arm Chin Up training

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, calisthenics, bodyweight

My current physical level right now is;

1. maximum 7 assisted one arm chin ups with hand on mid-way forearm.

   2. maximum 5 assisted one arm chin ups with hand on elbow
   3. maximum 1 assisted one arm chin up with hand on bicep

No idea how many non-stop pull ups/chin ups I can do in a row, 1 month ago was 9 in a row and then I started training the unilateral version only.

Searching on forums I'm getting some doubts since most people suggest that I will get one arm chin ups more easily by doing rope climbs without legs.

Are rope climbs(without the use of legs) superior to doing assisted one arm chin ups  when one's goal is achieving a full one arm chin up?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 2):

**I don't think there is a set way to train for a one arm chinup, you just have to be strong enough relative to your bodyweight.** You can train doing assisted one arm chinups the way you're doing, you can also do it with a resistance band. Rope climbs can potentially get you there aswell.

Personally I just trained regular pullups and chipups with additional weight attached to my body and one day I tried one arm chinups and I could do them.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this depends on your bodyweight. Anecdotally I've found heavier men (who have chunkier shoulders etc.) can find rope climbs (w/o legs) too easy to really aid in the mission of really conquering a one armed chin up. Those heavier (stronger) guys will only manage it with a lot of weight training - weighted chin ups and weight-assisted one arm chin ups. The hardest part for the latter is sometimes finding machines that have small enough resistance decrements towards the zero-resistence end. I assume you don't have a grip problem given what's asked.